# SQLSERVER - how to define a procedure for table id generation?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm application switching databases for my application from MySQL to SQLServer.

Today I implement a custom id generation strategy defined in an abstract class all POJOs use. This works, but I am only able to generate an id via the application.

With this database migration, I'd like, after creating the schema, define somewhere all the 'id' columns for all tables to use a procedure that returns a `SELECT NEWID();` query.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Main idea here is to allow data insertion either via the application and via insert sql scripts

Comment: I think you want [one or more sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to define the ID columns with a default constraint:

```
create table a
(
  id 
    uniqueidentifier not null
    constraint [a.id.default.newid]
      default( newid() )
    constraint [a.id.primarykey]
      primary key clustered,

  --> other columns...
)
```

This way, you can either take an app-generated ID or let the database assign it, depending on your needs. Your primary key constraint (or unique constraint) enforces uniqueness...which is important if you allow incoming IDs from the apps.

In the scripts...where you don't necessarily have the need to generate the ID, don't specify a value...and the default kicks in. You can insert `newid()`, too...

```
insert a 
select newid() 
from b
```

...and SQL Server knows to call `newid()` for each row

Comment: Thank you, buddy! That's exactly what I needed. I don't suppose there's a way to tell Hibernate to do this, is there?

Comment: @gtludwig, sorry...not familiar w/ hibernate